# Adding multiple locations for "Suggested Apps" in iOS8

Tags: ios, app-store, ios8, location-services

My question is: How can I add multiple locations to my iOS app so that it suggests the app to users at my customers' locations and not just my headquarters?

A little background: The "Suggested Apps" feature in iOS 8 adds an icon to the bottom left-hand screen of a user's phone when their location services are turned on and they are in the proximity of your application. This allows the user to simply swipe up on the icon to be directed to the App Store entry for that app or to open the application on their phone.

Large chains, such as Starbucks, would presumably expect that this would occur at each of their branches; for this to work, they would have to add each of those addresses to their app somehow. How can I add multiple addresses to take advantage of this feature?

Comment: Do you already have this working with your headquarter? Do you get app suggestion, for non-installed app?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar set of question.

Please have a look at my answer here on SO, maybe it'll give you a bit more insight into how this feature is controlled by Apple:

[iOS 8 Suggested Apps - How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680439/ios-8-suggested-apps-how-does-it-work/26680440#26680440)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the locations that will suggest your app.  It is driven by installs of the apps and their location (if the users have geolocation turned on).  I would suspect you are getting it at your main office (like I do with my company) because most of the employees will have the app installed on their phones.  That makes it seem like a "hot spot" to Apple, so it will then suggest it.  The reason it works with Starbucks and similar retail locations is that users go to Starbucks often have the app and will use it, triggering to Apple that it should recommend it to others, or have it pop up automatically when you arrive.

I think if your app does need to be tied specifically to a location (like a Mall map app), you can submit a bug report / feature request to Apple for consideration.